# What should we do about the [addressbook] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

I just noticed that we have the [addressbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/addressbook) tag. Its wiki entry starts out:

> An address book or a name and address book (NAB) is a book or a
>   database used for storing entries called contacts...

and continues through the definition of an address book that most of us are familiar with.

Flipping through the questions, it seems like there are a few iOS questions using the tag where the existing [abaddressbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/abaddressbook) tag could be usable instead. (I'm not an iOS guy, so I'd need input from those who are more familiar as to whether or not that's true in general)

Other than those types of questions though, we also have

[Deleting and modifying in Address Book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830663/deleting-and-modifying-in-address-book)

[Data structure for implementing an Address Book in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20243779/data-structure-for-implementing-an-address-book-in-java)

So then, should we make [addressbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/addressbook) a synonym of [abaddressbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/abaddressbook) and just retag the others (again, looking at the iOS community here for whether I'm just insane), burninate [addressbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/addressbook) completely, leave it alone, or some fourth option I haven't thought about?

Comment: Not sure whether to tag this with "retag-request" or "burninate-request". Also, the first linked question is where I realized this tag exists.

Comment: [I'm thinking](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ChmUC0OysoU)

Comment: I don't know about iOS, but if you are correct I'd burninate it